# Running batch with BCP commands via SQL Server Agent

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, bcp, sql-server-agent

When I run batch file with:

```
BCP "SELECT * FROM [KW_GRECOS].[dbo].[V_G076a]" queryout "G:\Bulk\V_G076a_new.bcp" -N -S localhost -T -E
BCP "[KW_GRECOS].[dbo].[hist_V_G076a]" IN "G:\Bulk\V_G076a_new.bcp" -N -S localhost -T -E -b 1000000 -h "CHECK_CONSTRAINTS"
```

It works perfectly, but when I execute same batch from job in SQL Server Agent:

```
cmd.exe /c "E:\batch\Bulk_copy.bat"
```

It's not working:

> Date,Source,Severity,Step ID,Server,Job Name,Step
>   Name,Notifications,Message,Duration,Sql Severity,Sql Message
>   ID,Operator Emailed,Operator Net sent,Operator Paged,Retries Attempted
>   12/21/2017 00:40:37,NightBulk,Error,,DBSERVER,NightBulk,,,The job
>   failed.  The Job was invoked by User eTour\ITcom.  The last step to
>   run was step 1 (1 Bulk insert).  The job was requested to start at
>   step 1 (1 Bulk insert).,00:00:00,0,0,,,,0 12/21/2017
>   00:40:37,NightBulk,Error,1,DBSERVER,NightBulk,1 Bulk insert,,Executed
>   as user: DBSERVER\ITcom. C:\Windows\system32>BCP "SELECT * FROM
>   [KW_eTour].[dbo].[V_G075a]" queryout "G:\Bulk\V_G075a_new.bcp" -N -S
>   localhost -T -E   SQLState = S1000 NativeError = 0  Error =
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Unable to open BCP host
>   data-file.  Process Exit Code 1.  The step failed.,00:00:00,0,0,,,,0

Answer (score 0):

It is due to insufficient permissions.

The SQL Server Agent service-user can not access the file `G:\Bulk\V_G075a_new.bcp`.

You have the following options:

- Move the file to a location where the service-user can access it.
- Modify the NTFS-permissions of the file/folder to allow the SQL Server Agent service-user to access the file

Comment: Folder "G:\Bulk\" has full control for Everyone, isin't that enough?